# Solve for $\rho$: $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}-u(t,x)\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}=\rho\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(t,x)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm trying to solve the PDE
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}-u(t,x)\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}=\rho\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(t,x)$$
for $\rho:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ for a given $u:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

By the method of characteristics we get
$$dt=\frac{dx}{-u}=\frac{d\rho}{\rho u_x}$$

So $$dx=-udt,$$
$$\frac{d\rho}{\rho}=\frac{u_x}{-u}dx\Rightarrow \rho=e^{A\int \frac{u_x}{-u}dx}$$
and
$$\frac{d\rho}{\rho}=u_x dt\Rightarrow \rho=e^{B\int u_xdt}.$$
I am not sure if this is right, and if it is, I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Your solution is wrong. I suspect the PDE cannot be solved in closed form if $u$ is an arbitrary function of $x$ and $t$.

Comment: @Gonçalo do you think that imposing stronger assumptions on u one can solve it?

Comment: It is possible to solve it if $u(x,t)=v(x)w(t)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo could you please answer the question in this case? I am not used to solve PDEs and I am having trouble with this one. I think I didn't quite understand this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote, the Lagrange-Charpit equations for the PDE
$$
\rho_t-u(t,x)\rho_x=\rho u_x(t,x) \tag{1}
$$
are given by
$$
dt=\frac{dx}{-u}=\frac{d\rho}{\rho u_x}. \tag{2}
$$
In the special case in which $u$ has the form $u(t,x)=w(t)v(x)$, we can rewrite $(2)$ as
$$
dt=\frac{dx}{-w(t)v(x)}=\frac{d\rho}{\rho w(t)v'(x)}. \tag{3}
$$
The first equality is now a separable ODE:
$$
dt=\frac{dx}{-w(t)v(x)}\implies \int_{0}^t w(s)\,ds=-\int_{0}^x\frac{dz}{v(z)}+C_1. \tag{4}
$$
The second equality in $(3)$ is also a separable ODE:
$$
\frac{dx}{-w(t)v(x)}=\frac{d\rho}{\rho w(t)v'(x)} \implies
\int\frac{d\rho}{\rho}=-\int\frac{v'(x)\,dx}{v(x)}
$$
$$
\implies \ln|\rho|=-\ln|v(x)|+C_2 \implies \rho=\frac{C_2}{v(x)}. \tag{5}
$$
From $(4)$ and $(5)$ it follows that
$$
\rho(t,x)=\frac{1}{v(x)}F\left(\int_{0}^t w(s)\,ds+\int_{0}^x\frac{dz}{v(z)}\right), \tag{6}
$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.